# Main.js Definitions Inconsistent from Module

Tags: javascript, webpack, phaser-framework

I am using the Phaser framework to create a game. I have two files, a `main.js` and a `Player.js` that is meant to hold the Player class.

main.js:

```
import 'pixi'
import Phaser from 'phaser'

import Player from './controllers/Player.js'

var game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 703, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload, 
    create: create, 
    update: update
});

var player;

function preload() {
    this.stage.backgroundColor = '#eee',
    this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true,
    this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true,
    this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL,

    game.load.spritesheet( 'idle', '../../assets/sheet_hero_idle.png', 64, 64 ),
    game.load.spritesheet( 'wall', '../../assets/roguelike-cave-pack/Spritesheet/roguelikeDungeon_transparent.png', 16, 16 )
}

function create() {
    //Player Controller
    //===========================
    //Enable Physics on the world
    game.physics.startSystem( Phaser.Physics.ARCADE );
    game.physics.arcade.setBoundsToWorld();

    //Enable input
    game.inputEnabled = true;

    //create player
    player = new Player( game, game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'idle' );
    game.add.existing( player ); //Create on screen
    game.physics.arcade.enable( player ); //Create physics body on this object

    console.log("player is\t", player); //TEST
    console.log("player body is\t", player.body); //TEST
    console.log("player body is enabled\t", player.body.enable); //TEST

    player.playAnim( 'idle', 10, true );

    game.input.onDown.add( player.thisIsMyBody, this ); //When a click input occurs, call player.thisIsMyBody()
```

Player.js:

```
export default function Player( game, x, y, animKey ) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call( this, game, x, y, animKey),
    this.anchor.setTo( 0.5 ),
    this.inputEnabled = true,
    this.assets = {
        animations: {}
    },
    this.animations.add( 'idle' ),
    this.animations.play( 'idle', 10, true ), 
    this.alive = true
};

Player.prototype = Object.create( Phaser.Sprite.prototype );

Player.prototype.constructor = Player;

Player.prototype.thisIsMyBody = function(){ //TEST
    console.log( "I am ", this );
    console.log( "My body is ", this.body);
},

Player.prototype.playAnim = function( key, speed, isLoop ) {
    this.animations.play( key, speed, isLoop );
},

Player.prototype.move = function() {
    this.body.velocity.x = 30;
}
```

`console.log("player is\t", player);` returns Player object

`console.log("player body is\t", player.body);` returns Player body

`console.log("player body is enabled\t", player.body.enable);` returns `true`

However, `player.thisIsMyBody` returns the `game` Object and `undefined`

Is there anything I am missing or some misuse of `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found the following to work:

```
this.player = new Player( game, game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'idle' );
game.add.existing( this.player ); //<--WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT
game.physics.arcade.enable( this.player );

game.camera.follow( this.player );
game.input.onDown.add( this.player.thisIsMyBody, this.player );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, you're misusing the `this` when binding to `input.onDown`.

Haven't tested it, but try changing

```
game.input.onDown.add(player.thisIsMyBody, this);
```

to

```
game.input.onDown.add(this.thisIsMyBody, player);
```

or possibly just

```
game.input.onDown.add(thisIsMyBody, player);
```

When adding a `Phaser.Signal` listener, the second parameter basically answers the question "What should `this` mean when calling the callback?".

Comment: Unfortunately, your first solution returns "Phaser.Signal: listener is a required param of add() and should be a Function", and your second solution returns "thisIsMyBody is not defined".

To comment on your rationale, if my second parameter is a `Player` object why would we need to call `game` as context for a `Player` method?